# How to change list item date time format type using c#

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, splistitem, date-time

I am making a sharepoint web appplication.

when I show the data from sharepoint lists, I want to change DateTime format type.

For example, "Created" item showed like this now [2017-06-15 PM 3:23:33]

But I only want to show [yyyy.mm.dd] format type.

How can I change that? my code is below.

```
 private void GetListGroupNews(StringBuilder sb, SPListItemCollection listItemCol) 
 { 
    try 
    { 
       if (listItemCol.Count > 0) 
       { 
          for (int i = 0; i < listItemCol.Count; i++) 
          { 
              string itemTitle = string.Empty; 
              string itemBody = string.Empty;  
              string itemRegDate = string.Empty; 

              itemTitle = listItemCol[i]["Title"] == null ? "" : listItemCol[i]["Title"].ToString(); 
              itemBody = listItemCol[i]["Body"] == null ? "" : listItemCol[i]["Body"].ToString(); 
              //I want to convert this
              itemRegDate = listItemCol[i]["Created"] == null ? "" : listItemCol[i]["Created"].ToString();

              //codes.....
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(listItemCol[i]["Created"]);

itemRegDate = date.ToString("yyyy.mm.dd");
```

Comment: I modified your code a little bit, and it works well! thanks Gautam Sheth